# mpdf page numbering {PAGENO} with smarty template engine

Tags: php, smarty, mpdf

I want to use `pagenumbering` in `mpdf` with tags how its described in `mpdf` manual:

http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=109

Problem is I have used smarty template engine and there I can not use mpdf tag {PAGENO} in *header/footer* direct in html template, because I think smarty expected in {} parentheses variables. ( example `{$test}` )

So when I define {PAGENO}, smarty get syntax error: unrecognized tag 'PAGENO'  ...

also I have tried to call this metod, but it's not working->when I generate pdf, in generated pdf is nothing regarding page numbering:

// Set a simple Footer including the page number

$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');

Have anybody some idea, how I could use `mpdf` page numbering with smarty template engine?

thx

Comment: @Sandesh: please don't use code spans (`like this`) to highlight terms that you think are important. Code spans are only intended for variables or parts of code in sentences. For more information, please take a look at [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [{literal}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal) in your html template:

```
{literal}{PAGENO}{/literal}
```